# How to get different values from different tables in Treeview / Tkinter (SQLite)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

I've been working with Tkinter and I'm trying to get different columns from different tables in my Treeview, I'm using SQLite as database, in my first table called **registers** i got different columns **idcard, name, surname, cellphone, address, email, etc** in my second table named **attendance** I use to store my entries attendances by ID number I mean I got two entries `cardin = entry1` and `cardout = entry1` so if one of my entries match with my **registers table idcard**, it automatically store **idcard, timein, timeout, date** in my **attendance table** till that it works so good, but I can´t get the **names, surnames columns** from my first table **registers** and store them in my second table **attendace** same as my **idcard, timein, timeout, date** (the idcard, names, surnames must match from the first table), I was trying to solve it but I falied, I really have no idea how to do it, any help thanls in advance. have a good day. Here is my code:

```py
def botoningreso():

    time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    cardin = entry1.get()
    cardout = entry2.get()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM registers WHERE idcard = ? OR idcard = ?', (cardin, cardout))

    if c.fetchall():
        messagebox.showinfo(title='ID Registered', message='Registered Succefully')
        c.execute("INSERT INTO attendance (timein, idcard, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (time, cardin, date)) #Here i also wanto to save *names and surnames* from the first table *registers* that match with the idcard column.
        conn.commit()

    else:
        messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Wrong ID card')

    c.close()
```

Comment: In short, you want to get the username and surname from first table that has the id you insert into second table?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes man, untill now I just got **idcard, timein, timeout and date** in my second table once I enter a right idcard stored in my first data table.

Comment: What is the output of `print(c.fetchall()` before the `if`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried to `print(c.fetchall()` before if but it didn't give me any value

Comment: Doesn't that mean your query is not returning any result and is wrong?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes I think so, What should I do?, My interfaces entries are working good with my database once I enter a right idcard it matches and INSERT idcard, timein, timeout and date VALUES into my second datatable normally.

Comment: Its probably a generator issue. Anyway store `data = c.fetchall()` and use `data` instead. Which means `data[0][1]` and `data[0][2]` and `data[0][3]` is what your looking for.

Comment: @CoolCloud I wrote `data = c.fetchall() print(data)` after **c.execute(......) and before if**  and I realized that my entry isnt matching my idcard numbers anymore, also I got as output VALUES of my **registers** table which is [(idcardnumer, 'name1', 'surname1'], I dont know why because what I have in my first table right now is [(idcardnumner2, 'name1', 'surname1'], [(idcardnumer2, 'name2', 'surname2']

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried to give new VALUES for my table **registers** in my database (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) and also in the next row a new register (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) and when I run my program I only get as output the first row VALUES of my table **registers** [("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")] , I don't get my second row values.

Comment: Because your input for id is 1?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, I'm just trying to fill in the idcard number, name, surname, cellphone, address columns with **1** and repeat the same with **2** just in order to show you the output result. I mean right now in my **registers** table I have the following columns 'idcard, name, surname, address, email' and in the first row I just filled up all the columns values with **1** and for the second row with **2** , then u tried to run the code you told me `data = c.fetchall() print(data)` and I just got the first row of my table **registers** that is [("1", "1", "1", "1", "1")]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229366/discussion-between-cool-cloud-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a variable to fetched data and then index it and proceed:

```py
data = c.fetchall()

if data:
    username = data[0][1] # Access username from fetched list
    surname = data[0][2] # Access surname

    messagebox.showinfo(title='ID Registered', message='Registered Succefully')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO attendance (timein,idcard,date,user,sur) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (time,cardin,date,username,surname)) 
    conn.commit()
```

It is important to assign variable to `c.fetchall()` as it behaves like a generator object and loses its items once its been used.